# Use HTML legend in QGIS

Tags: qgis, legend, html

I am trying to set up HTML text in a legend of this kind: `<div style = 'padding: 0; margin-left: -10px; color: # 7f7f7f '> O-1 <span style =' color: black '> - Kind of zone </span> </div>`, but the button render as HTML is only in the text properties.
How can I use HTML in a layout legend?

Answer (score 1):

There's no "render as html" support for legends in any way (yet).
If you want to build a legend with html you need to use a html frame.
If you want graphics you could combine a legend without any text with a html frame styled the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

This has been introduced on the last release, QGIS 3.30, as announced [here](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog330/#print-layouts) and it is fully functional.